# If $f$ is a bounded non-decreasing function, then it converges as $x \to \infty$ and as $x \to -\infty$. (Obvious?)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Here's a dumb one.

This is a result that seems intuitively true, but I cannot find an actual statement of it anywhere, which leads me to believe there is some weird counterexample out there somewhere.

*Remark.* I am aware of the monotone convergence theorem for *sequences*, but I do not see a result anywhere for functions. Rather than try to modify the proof of the MCT for sequences, I'm just going to try to prove the result directly.

**Proposition.**

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, non-decreasing function. Then
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) $$
exist.

**Proof of Proposition.**

Let $\alpha = \inf\{f(\mathbb{R})\}$ and $\beta = \sup\{f(\mathbb{R})\}$. Since $f$ is bounded, both of these extrema exist and, clearly, $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset [\alpha, \beta]$. Since $f$ is non-decreasing,
$$ x \le y \implies \alpha \le f(x) \le f(y) \le \beta, $$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ (so $f$ cannot exhibit any "oscillating" behavior"). So assume WLOG that $\beta$ is positive. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > \beta - \epsilon$ whenever $x \ge b$. Therefore
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \beta. $$
A similar proof shows that $f(x) \to \alpha$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$.

Eh?

Comment: A function that goes up and down and up and down ... is non-decreasing, at least if this is defined as the negation of decreasing.

Comment: I would interprete "non-decreasing" as "nowhere (strictly) decreasing"

Comment: Can we assume that the function is continous ?

Comment: No, the function is not necessarily continuous (think of step functions).

Comment: A function is non-decreasing if it is "increasing" (by some conventions), but not necessarily strictly increasing. This allows for things like constant functions and step functions.

Comment: This seems very similar to the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Did you read my Remark at the top of my post?

Comment: Well the proof on Wikipedia never uses the fact that $n\in\mathbb N$ so you could just take $n\in\mathbb R$ and get exactly your result

Comment: The modern terminology is that $f$ is increasing if $x<y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$ and $f$ is strictly increasing if $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$ and $f$ is decreasing if $x<y\implies f(x)\ge f(y)$ and $f$ is strictly decreasing if $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y).$ So it is not safe to use "non-decreasing" when you  mean "increasing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is non decreasing and bounded, let $L = \sup f(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\epsilon>0$, then by definition there is some $x^*$ such that $f(x^*) >L-\epsilon$. Since $f$
is non decreasing, $L \ge f(x) \ge f(x^*) > L-\epsilon$ for all $x \ge x^*$.

In particular $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and so $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =L$.

The same approach works for the other direction.

Comment: So, in other words, the proposition is true, and my proof of it is sufficient (since yours is nearly identical to mine)?

Comment: Yes. Also, it is sufficient to show that $f(x_n) \to L$ for any sequence $x_n \to \infty$. $f(x_n)$ is not quite a monotonic sequence, but it is 'monotonic enough'.